# Url.Action cant find controller method which returns RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a javascript funtion that will called a controller method if the condition satisfied.

[image: In the]

In SilentLogout method, it returns RedirectToAction method.

[image]

For this SilentLogout method, there is no view associated with it.

The codes work well except it cannot find the the SilentLogout.
[image]

Just fyi, there are other methods in this controller which returns view and it all works well.

Comment: Pls, show the whole javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `window.location.href` performs a "GET".
Unless there's a `[HttpGet]` sitting above your `[HttpPost]` you've locked that action to "POST" only. Just remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute. there's probably no reason to lock down a logout method anyway.